# Free text for drop down

Tags: business-process-management, ibm-bpm

I want to allow the user either to type the text by himself or select it from the drop down.
Is it possible to allow free text for a drop-down box in bpm? 
If yes, Please explain how it has to be implemented

Comment: Can you please clarify what (business process execution) system you are using? BPM (business process management) is a management discipline, not a specific system.

Comment: I am using BPM 8.6.0